# Undefined reference to 'vtable for ...'

Tags: c++

first steps in cpp studies and I'm sturggling with an issue -
when trying to compile my unfinished code, i get error
Undefined reference to 'vtable for ...'
I searched for previous question and seems it has to do with virtual function I missed defining, but I passed on my code and couldn't find my error.

*I tried playing with destructor of Agent, nothing worked for me.

header file:

```
#ifndef SPL_ASSIGNMENT1_AGENT_H
#define SPL_ASSIGNMENT1_AGENT_H

#include <vector>
#include "Session.h"



class Agent{
public:
    Agent();
    virtual ~Agent()=0;
    virtual Agent* clone() const;
    virtual void act(Session& session)=0;
};

class ContactTracer: public Agent{
public:
    ContactTracer();
    ~ContactTracer();
    ContactTracer(const ContactTracer& other);
    ContactTracer* clone() const;

    virtual void act(Session& session);
};


class Virus: public Agent{
public:
    Virus(int _nodeInd);
    Virus(const Virus& vir);
    ~Virus();
    Virus* clone() const;

    virtual void act(Session& session);
private:
    const int nodeInd;
};

#endif //SPL_ASSIGNMENT1_AGENT_H
```

cpp file:

```
//
// Created by galyo on 03/11/2020.
//

#include "Agent.h"
#include "iostream"


Agent::Agent() {}





//============RULE OF 5============

//Empty constructor
ContactTracer::ContactTracer() {
        //IMPLEMENTED
}

//COPY constructor
ContactTracer::ContactTracer(const ContactTracer &other) {
    //IMPLEMENTED
}


//Destruct
ContactTracer::~ContactTracer() {}


ContactTracer *ContactTracer::clone() const {
    return new ContactTracer(*this);
}

//void ContactTracer::act(Session &session) {} //TBD

//============================================================================

//========= RULE OF 5=============

//constructor
Virus::Virus(int _nodeInd):nodeInd(_nodeInd) {
        //IMPLEMENTED!!!
}
//copy constructor
Virus::Virus(const Virus& vir):nodeInd(vir.nodeInd) {
        //IMPLEMENTED!!!
}
//destructor
Virus::~Virus() {
    delete &nodeInd;
}

//void Virus::act(Session &session) {} TBD!!!

Virus *Virus::clone() const {
    return new Virus(*this);
}
```

Comment: The problem lies with `Agent::clone`. It doesn't have a definition, but it's also not declared pure virtual like `Agent::act`. Tangentially, you probably don't want the `~Agent` destructor to be pure virtual and would rather have `virtual ~Agent() = default;`.

Comment: I could not find your `Agent::~Agent() { }` or `Agent::~Agent() = default;` anywhere.